# No se marcan los datos que subo en una jsp

Tags: java, mysql

Creo que este es el código más complicado por el cual voy a pedir ayuda, miren, tengo iniciada la sesión en un usuario y puse un script de este modo para seguir dentro de la misma sesión dentro de las páginas desarrolladas

```
<script>
<%
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(false);
    String nombre = (String)sesion.getAttribute("nombre");
    String empresa = (String)sesion.getAttribute("empresa");
    if (nombre.equals("")) { 
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>  
</script>
```

Y si, como acaban de ver, lo inicio con nombre, contraseña que obviamente no lo marco aquí, como van a creer, y aparte tiene como restricción la empresa, así inicio sesión, hasta ahí todo bien. Lo tétrico viene cuando hice otra tabla, totalmente distinta a la de los usuarios, entonces cuando yo intento subir dichos datos a una jsp

```
<script>
<%
    Consultas c = new Consultas(); 
    String solic = request.getParameter("solicitante");
%>
</script>

<div><% out.println(solic);%></div>
```

incluso con form action y la acción de la clase que la subió no la acepta, no funciona, siempre me devuelve el resultado en null, lo curioso es que si le quito el script de la sesión si me devuelve el resultado, pero ese no es el chiste, necesito sacar el resultado dentro de la sesión, de hecho iniciando la sesión ya me pasó que quise marcar el usuario, porque nombre y empresa no son los únicos datos de la sesión, también usuario, pero el usuario nunca me lo marcó y también me lo marcó null y eso que eran de la misma tabla, el de los usuarios, entonces imagínense como no iba a reaccionar con una tabla diferente a la de usuarios y tengo como otro inconveniente que dentro de las consultas quiero agregar un dato entero para llamar un dato string y un dato int

```
<script>
    <%
        Consultas c = new Consultas(); 
        String solic = request.getParameter("solicitante");
        int folio = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("folio"));
    %>
</script>
```

Bueno con el dato entero es peor porque me devuelve este error sin siquiera todavía llamarla al out println

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.jsp.subirrequis_jsp._jspService(subirrequis_jsp.java:80)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho, muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa todo lo que trae el request. Te marca un **NumberFormatException** porque el parámetro ``folio`` es null.

Comment: como ? le estoy poniendo el integer parse int para que pueda requestear, de otro modo no habría reacción, como que está null?

Comment: En el Stack se indica el null: ``Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null``   Puedes revisar la documentación oficial del lenguaje: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html

Comment: Revisa las líneas 542 y 615 de tu código. Ahí manda el **NumberFormatException**